# How to remove Rust clippy warning `consider using the `vec![]` macro: `let mut https: Vec<u8> = vec![..];`

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

I have below rust code.

```rust
let mut https: Vec<u8>= Vec::new();
https.push(b'/');
```

When I am running `cargo clippy`, I am getting below warning

```
warning: calls to `push` immediately after creation
  https.push(b'/');
                  ^ help: consider using the `vec![]` macro: `let mut https: Vec<u8> = vec![..];`
```

Can somebody please help me to remove this warning?

Comment: As the compiler suggests, the warning can be removed this way: `let mut https: Vec<u8>= vec![b'/'];`.

Comment: Relevant section from the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-01-vectors.html#storing-lists-of-values-with-vectors

Comment: The downvote was probably because the error message literally tells you how to solve it.

Comment: Putting aside the compiler suggests you how to solve it, this is also a duplicate (of two questions!) I'd expect the OP to research before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Clippy is advising that instead of pushing the new value manually you use the `vec![]` macro to construct a vector with the given items:

```rust
let https: Vec<u8> = vec![b'/'];
```